# Javafx adding Image in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to add image in `tableView` but I can't add image.

I am  getting image in `byte[]` and I can set this image in `imageView` but is there any way to add it in `tableView`?

`person3` class:

```
public class person3 {
    private final StringProperty firstName7 = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final StringProperty firstName8 = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public person3(String firstName4, String firstName5) {
        setFirstName7(firstName4);
        setFirstName8(firstName5);
    }

    public String getFirstName7() {
        return firstName7.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName7(String name) {
        this.firstName7.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty7() {
        return firstName7;
    }

    public String getFirstName8() {
        return firstName8.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName8(String name) {
        this.firstName8.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty8() {
        return firstName8;
    } 
}
```

Now I am trying to add image in `tableview`:

```
f51 = rs.getBytes(10); 
System.out.println(f51);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(f51);
System.out.println(bis);
BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(bis);
System.out.println(read);
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(read, null);
table1.getItems().add(new person3("Data1", "data2"));
// this add simple data but how can I add image
```

Would like to get any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

One of the posible approach for this issue is to create simple class, lets say `CustomImage` with private `ImageView` object initialization and its setter and getter. Next, you can use this class to specify `TableView<T>` and `TableColumn<T>` generic types, set column's cell value factory, and populate table with your images. Implementation of example `CustomImage` class and its practical use is shown below:

```
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class CustomImage {

    private ImageView image;

    CustomImage(ImageView img) {
        this.image = img;
    }

    public void setImage(ImageView value) {
        image = value;
    }

    public ImageView getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Practical implementation:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageViewInTableView extends Application {

    public Parent createContent() {

        /* layout */
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        /* layout -> center */
        TableView<CustomImage> tableview = new TableView<CustomImage>();

        /* layout -> center -> tableview */

        /* initialize two CustomImage objects and add them to the observable list */
        ObservableList<CustomImage> imgList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        CustomImage item_1 = new CustomImage(new ImageView(new Image("Icon_AddNewPatient.png")));
        CustomImage item_2 = new CustomImage(new ImageView(new Image("Icon_EditPatient.png")));
        imgList.addAll(item_1, item_2);

        /* initialize and specify table column */
        TableColumn<CustomImage, ImageView> firstColumn = new TableColumn<CustomImage, ImageView>("Images");
        firstColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CustomImage, ImageView>("image"));
        firstColumn.setPrefWidth(60);

        /* add column to the tableview and set its items */
        tableview.getColumns().add(firstColumn);
        tableview.setItems(imgList);

        /* add TableView to the layout */
        layout.setCenter(tableview);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setWidth(200);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And thats how it looks like:

[image]