# JavaFX Image (class) and ImageView with a URL

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I know how to use Image with a url there was a good example here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934324/7159163

However, when I input a URL into the string it doesn't work although the Javadocs say if it not a URL it will try to find the file. But it is a URL and its just not displaying.

All that has been changed is 
`CustomImage item_2 = new CustomImage(new ImageView(new Image("url:https://pictureOfCat")));`

Comment: Try removing "url:" prefix. Is it works then?

Comment: Nope I have tried without. With "URL:" with "url:" but still nothing.

Comment: See answer. Sorry you were somewhat correct!

Comment: It should be just `https://whatever`.  Try it with a plain http:// url from some known working internet image to ensure it's not just some connectivity problem (like, say, the server doesn't like your certs in the https case)

Comment: @Mark yes, because URLs don't need 'url:' prefix. Thing before ':' is access protocol, and, in your case, 'https'. Great that it works with 'http', but using 'https' is another issue (if you really need it of course).

Comment: Yes indeed it was httpS causing the issue. (and "url:")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomImage item_2 = new CustomImage(new ImageView(new 
Image("http://pictureOfCat")));`

The issue is "https" when I changed it to "http" it worked fine! And removing "url:"

So @Vyacheslav Zhukov had the right idea though! - I didn't think https would make a difference.